# unable to delete or remove single sign on cookie in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

```
string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
{
    Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
 {

     HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
     myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
     Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
 }
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)